# Get Description for Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following code that searches and lists through various parameters of spreadsheets on Google Drive with a user input search term.

How can I alter the code to take the "Description" of the *current active Google spreadsheet?* (newbie) I just cannot seem to make it work: only via the search option

```
function onOpen() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var searchMenuEntries = [ {name: "Search in all files", functionName: "search"}];
    ss.addMenu("Search Google Drive", searchMenuEntries);
}
function search() {

    // Prompt the user for a search term
    var searchTerm = Browser.inputBox("Enter the search parameters");

    // Get the active spreadsheet and the active sheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

    // Search the files in the user's Google Drive for the search term
    var files = DriveApp.searchFiles("fullText contains '" + searchTerm.replace("'", "\'") + "'");

    // Create an array to store our data to be written to the sheet.
    var output = [];

    // Loop through the results and get the file name, file type, and URL.
    while (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        var fileId = file.getId();
        var updated = file.getLastUpdated();

        var fileType = file.getMimeType();
        if (fileType === MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS) {
            var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId);
            var name = doc.getName();
            var description = file.getDescription();
            var url = doc.getUrl();

            var range = doc.getRange("A1:C11");
            var tags = range.getCell(1, 2).getValue(); 
            var email = range.getCell(11, 2).getValue();
            var mobile = range.getCell(7, 2).getValue();

            // Push the file details to our output array (essentially pushing a row of data).
            output.push([ tags, name, email, mobile, description, url, updated, fileId]);
        }
    }

    // Set up the spreadsheet to display the results.
    var headers = [["Tags", "File Name", "Email", "Mobile", "Description", "URL", "Updated", "File ID"]];
    sheet.clear();
    sheet.getRange("A1:H1").setValues(headers);

    // Write data to the original sheet.
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, output.length, 8).setValues(output);
}
```

Any help gratefully received. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest writing a new function (e.g. `writeDescription()`), instead of breaking the `search()` function, and adding a reference to it from `onOpen` so you can call it easily.

In your new function, you probably don't want to clear the active sheet - I would recommend accessing a specific sheet instead, i.e.

```
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Wb Description');
if(!sheet)
    sheet = ss.createSheet('Wb Description');
sheet.clear();
```

As [i-i](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/i-i) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49033286/get-description-for-google-spreadsheet#comment85073013_49033286), you still need to use the Drive API to obtain the desired information about a file:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId());
var description = file.getDescription();
```

If the description is all you want, then you just need to write it:

```
sheet.getRange("A1:A2").setValues([["Description:"], [description]]);
```

The above line would then write "Description" into A1 and the spreadsheet's description into A2.